# Nested NDSolve with WhenEvent: setting up new equations and discarding old ones

Tags: differential-equations, meta-programming

I am checking a complex situation where a function `x1[t1]` only exit in a finite time span, and after this a new function `x2[t2]` will be set up according to the final value of `x1`, and then repeat the same procedure to build `x3[t3]`, ..., `xn[tn]`.

A most simple 3-nest toy code can be rawly formatted like this

```
d0 = 1;
{c1, c2, c3} = {1, 2, 3};
end=20;

res1 = NDSolve[{
   x1'[t1] == c1, x1[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[x1[t1] == d0,
    res2 = NDSolve[{
       x2'[t2] == c2, x2[t1] == x1[t1],
       WhenEvent[x2[t2] == 2*d0,
        res3 = NDSolve[{
           x3'[t3] == c3, x3[t2] == x2[t2]
           }, x3, {t3, t2, end}, MaxSteps -> 1000000];
        "StopIntegration"
        ]}, x2, {t2, t1, end}, MaxSteps -> 1000000];
    "StopIntegration"
    ]}, x1, {t1, 0, end}, MaxSteps -> 1000000];
```

We can now check `res1`, `res2` and `res3`, and they work. But I hope that this code can be more concise than its current state, like how we discard the previous functions and code the remaining inner-nest part, especially for multiple-nest cases, ie. a 100-nest case. I think the most proper way would be to go meta-programming together with recursion... am I right?

---

**Update**

Based on Albert Retey's answer, we can furthe treat x[t] as a vector function, like this

```
cVals = {{1, 1/2}, {1/3, 1/4}, {1/5, 1/10}};
tvals = {5, 10, 20};
tstart = 0;
xsol = Quiet[
   NDSolveValue[{
     x'[t] == cVals[[n[t]]], x[tstart] == {0, 0}, n[tstart] == 1,
     WhenEvent[t == tvals[[n[t]]],
      If[TrueQ[n[t] < Length[cVals]], n[t] -> n[t] + 1, "RemoveEvent"]]
     }, x, {t, tstart, 20},
    DiscreteVariables -> {Element[n, Integers]}, MaxSteps -> 1000000
    ], Part::pspec];

Plot[xsol[t], {t, ##}] &[Sequence @@ xsol["Domain"][[1]]]
```

[image]

Where we used `cVals = {{1, 1/2}, {1/3, 1/4}, {1/5, 1/10}}`.

I think the code can be more general if we can use something like `cVals = {1, {1/2, 1/3}, {1/4, 1/5, 1/6}}` so that the `x[t]` can have variable dimensions at different time scopes. I wonder if this idea is feasible?

---

**Update 2**

Here is a first try, which shows the idea, but the code does not work yet...

```
cVals = {1, {1/2, 1/3}};
tvals = {5, 10};
tstart = 0;
xsol = Quiet[
   NDSolveValue[{
     x'[t] == cVals[[n[t]]], x[tstart] == 0, n[tstart] == 1,
     WhenEvent[t > tvals[[n[t]]],
      If[TrueQ[n[t] < Length[cVals]],
       xv = x[t];
       n[t] -> n[t] + 1;
       x[t] -> {xv, xv},
       "RemoveEvent"]]
     }, x, {t, tstart, 20},
    DiscreteVariables -> {Element[n, Integers]}, MaxSteps -> 1000000
    ], Part::pspec];

Plot[xsol[t], {t, ##}] &[Sequence @@ xsol["Domain"][[1]]]
```

Comment: It's not very hard to write code that does what you want, but why do you think you need to nest these `NDSolves`? As far as I understand you are just stopping at certain conditions and then run another `NDSolve` with the final point of the previous as initial conditions, stop that at another condition and so on. No need for a recursion at all. In fact as only a parameter changes in your restarted equations you could handle that within the `WhenEvent` without even restarting...

Comment: @Albert Retey, we can consider the case for this question as a single "path", and the real case I am checking is the coupling among many such paths. During the weekends I have written a code that "mimic" the `NDSolve` results (as in the question, where the ODE is assumed linear for simplicity) happening at time t1, t2, ... for the multiple paths' coupling. It uses only a single `While` for dynamic looping. The real problem can be solved by developing an XFEM kink-enrichment method, but for comparison it will be better if we can use finite difference method to solve the problem to some extent.

Comment: @Albert Retey, as you said, it is possible to handle the parameter changing within the `WhenEvent` without restarting. But how can we do this? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it is possible for the example you have shown to achieve the same thing without a recursion and without even restarting `NDSolve`. The trick is to introduce a discrete variable which is changed at each event. Here is something that I think does the same thing as your code:

```
cVals = {1, 2, 3};
tstart = 0;
xsol = Quiet[NDSolveValue[{
     x'[t] == cVals[[n[t]]], x[tstart] == 0, n[tstart] == 1,
     WhenEvent[x[t] == n[t]*1,
      If[TrueQ[n[t] < Length[cVals]], n[t] -> n[t] + 1, "RemoveEvent"]
      ]
     },
    x, {t, tstart, 20},
    DiscreteVariables -> {Element[n, Integers]},
    MaxSteps -> 1000000
    ], Part::pspec];

Plot[xsol[t], {t, (xsol@"Domain")[[1, 1]], (xsol@"Domain")[[1, 2]]}]
```

the code should work for lists of arbitrary length for `cVals`. The `Quiet` for `Part::pspec` is necessary because the equations will be evaluated for symbolic values of `n[t]`. It could be avoided by defining e.g. `cc[n_?NumericQ]:=cVals[[n]]` and use that in the first equation.

For other cases you might not be able to reformulate the switch in such a way, but then the first thing I'd try would be a loop, here is code which does that:

```
c = {1, 2, 3}; d0 = 1; tstart = 0; tend = 20;

solution[n_, nmax_] := Module[{t},
   x[n] = NDSolveValue[{
      x[n]'[t] == c[[n]], x[n][tstop[n - 1]] == x[n - 1][tstop[n - 1]],
      If[n == nmax,
       Unevaluated[Sequence[]],
       WhenEvent[x[n][t] == n*d0, "StopIntegration"]
       ]
      },
     x[n], {t, tstop[n - 1], tend}, MaxSteps -> 1000000
     ];
   tstop[n] = (x[n]@"Domain")[[1, 2]];
   ];

tstop[0] = tstart; x[0][tstart] = 0;

Do[solution[n, Length[c]], {n, 1, Length[c]}]
```

This checks that the solutions are really calculated as desired:

```
DownValues[x] // TableForm
```

Compared to writing the same thing by nesting this won't run into any iteration limit problems. Anyway, for completeness here is code which does what I think is closest to what was asked for originially, a recursive function:

```
c = {1, 2, 3};
d0 = 1;
x[0][0] = 0;
tend = 20;

solution[n_, nmax_, tprev_] := Module[{t},
   res[n] = NDSolve[{
       x[n]'[t] == c[[n]], x[n][tprev] == x[n - 1][tprev],
       If[n == nmax,
        Unevaluated[Sequence[]],
        WhenEvent[x[n][t] == n*d0, solution[n + 1, nmax, t]; 
         "StopIntegration"]
        ]
       },
      x[n], {t, tprev, tend}, MaxSteps -> 1000000
      ];
   ];

solution[1, Length[c], 0];

DownValues[res]
```

Comment: This is beautiful code, great! However, I think my code still has its usage, because in coupling case, at interaction points, not only the previous equation should be discarded, we also need to build a sequence of new equations, not a single one. Thus, no one knows exactly how many equations would evently be built before getting the real code running. This is why I was thinking in the direction of meta programming. But your code has already enlightened me, thanks!

Comment: @saturasl: while it is in principle possible to switch off equations for certains periods of time by changing their coefficients so that they  become trivial (e.g. `x'[t]==0`) using the `WhenEvent` mechanism I also think that there are cases where things become easier and probably more efficient if one restarts `NDSolve`. I would usually use a normal loop for such cases, where the start condition are determined from the last state of the previous run. I'll probably post code for that when I find a little spare time...

Comment: I agree. The switch can be controlled either from outside or inside 'NDSolve'. There should be no nesting-limit for controlling from outside; whereas from inside `NDSolve` may run into some limit. Thank you for updating.

Comment: I tested and the result shows that your using of normal loop `Do` is reasonable. As in nonlinear PDE case, each calling of `solution` will take longer time and so the difference between using `Do` and `Nest` or `Fold` like loops are neglectable. +1 for your example code! And I do wish to see the extra code you mentioned, if you have enough time...